# window.pageYOffset or just pageYOffset? / X + IEnumber+ pageYOffset / X support?

Tags: javascript, window, scrolltop

**1)**
I've noticed that (at least in Chrome) there is no difference in output of these two:

```
pageYOffset;
window.pageYOffset;
```

they both access the same global thus return the same - what is the difference between these calls and what is better to use?

***My current suspicion:*** I suspect the look-for-variables implementation, my idea is that window.pageYOffset is the direct access to the window object for the pageYOffset property whereas runing just pageYOffset will "slowly" look to every scope from deep to top and finaly finds it in the (super)global scope. What do you think? Did anybody make any tests?

**2)** what IEnumber+ supports window.pageYOffset / or just pageYOffset ?

 **2) Answer:** MDN says that IE<9 doesnt support those, so answer to the 2) is problably IE9+ (no surprise)

source: @Blender & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollY

Comment: Always check the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollY

Comment: `window.foo` and `foo` refer to the same global. I tend to be explicit and use `window.foo`.

Comment: `window` is the global object and all globals are properties of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Global_variables

Comment: @Blender Yes but that still doesnt explain the difference in calls ... Joe Simmons agreed with my suspicion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `window.` prefix is faster because, as you mentioned, there is no lookup. Also it won't mess up if you define a local variable called 'pageYOffset' because it will still look at window.pageYOffset.

I like it because it's more explicit and there is less confusion.

EDIT: The difference is the lookup, obviously.